# how to add a hook for Ctrl+S event in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, command, save, hook

Whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in eclipse to save source code I want some custom CMD on shell to run on my CentOS host. How can I do that?

Comment: Your face looks really familiar... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet is to add an external builder to your project.  You can choose to run an ant script or an arbitrary program (like /bin/bash) with arguments  of your choice.  Every time a project resource is saved (like a file) your builder will be run.  See [Ant Project Builders](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm) for a discussion on external builders.

The Java Editor has Save Actions that can be activated and customized, but AFAIK they don't include the ability to run a program.  See `Preferences > Java > Editors`.

If you can write plugins, you can also add an `org.eclipse.core.commands.IExecutionListener` to the `org.eclipse.ui.commands.ICommandService` and listen for the Save command (`org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_SAVE`).  Then you can do anything that you can write in java.  But the external project builders are probably the fastest way to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're Java in Eclipse... no.

Java natively can't hook keyboards or mouses. The only way to register keys is when the java app is focused.

C or C++ is the way to go for hooks.

You could do some searching for a Java wrapper that wraps a C/C++ hook. That's the only way really.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer is that is not possible...but you can achieve sth similar.

Yo will need to install and configure a  [CI server](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to poll for repository changes often and execute on every commit.

You can provide a key shortcut for "commit" on the eclipse Key pref page, so you might use it right after Ctrl+S

There is a [XShell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin) for Jenkins which you may find useful for your scripting.

Comment: OP didn't ask for command to be triggered at each commit but whenever a file is saved...

Comment: And the response to OP request is in the very first sentence. The rest offers a potential workaround for what I assumed OP might want to achieve.